# How to create pair of vector that are complementary to each other based on source vector in R

Tags: r

I have the following source vector:

```
source_vec <- c(1:3)
```

What I want to do is to enumerate the vector by splitting into two when one value is selected the other vector is complementary. 
Finally, it'll look like this (do by hand):

```
  from  to
  1,2    3
  1,3    2
  2,3    1
```

Note that the `to` column only one value, but from can be many.

Ideally, the final output is a dataframe/tibble, but `from` column is a [list column](https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/exploratory-data-analysis-in-r-case-study/tidy-modeling-with-broom?ex=10).

How can I achieve that with R?

Comment: Do you want a string column 'from' or `list`

Comment: You deleted the question although you could do `dat %>% filter(peptide_name == !!peptide_name)` or even `dat %>% filter(peptide_name == {{peptide_name}})` To disambiguate between the column name and the variable\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option with `base R` using `combn` to get the pairwise combinations and then create a `list` with the values and the element not found using `setdiff` with 'source_vec'

```
m1 <- combn(source_vec, 2)
lst1 <- apply(m1, 2, function(x) list(from = x, to = setdiff(source_vec, x)))
```

and then convert to a `tbl_df`

```
library(tidyr)
tibble(col1 = lst1) %>% 
     unnest_wider(col1)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  from         to
#  <list>    <int>
#1 <int [2]>     3
#2 <int [2]>     2
#3 <int [2]>     1
```

returns the 'from' as `list` column and 'to' as normal column

It can also be written as

```
combn(source_vec, 2, FUN = function(x)
    tibble(from = x, to = setdiff(source_vec, x)), simplify = FALSE) %>%
     bind_rows %>%
     group_by(to) %>% 
     summarise(from = toString(from)) %>%
     select(from, to)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  from     to
#  <chr> <int>
#1 2, 3      1
#2 1, 3      2
#3 1, 2      3
```

---

Or as @thelatemail mentioned in the comments

```
cmb <- combn(source_vec, 2, simplify=FALSE)
data.frame(from = I(cmb), to = sapply(cmb, setdiff, x=source_vec))
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I convert that into tibble?

Comment: Thanks again. But how can I name the column properly?

Comment: your last solution with `FUN` doesn't seem to work with `source_vec <- c(1:5)` or other.

Comment: sorry, i didn't test it thoroughtly, removed

Comment: Thanks but with `crossing` seems to work. Nice solution.

Comment: A variation on the `combn` approach is to not `simplify=` at the start, which will make things easier to combine - `cmb <- combn(source_vec, 2, simplify=FALSE); data.frame(from = I(cmb), to = sapply(cmb, setdiff, x=source_vec)) `

Comment: @akrun Do you mind looking at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59278992/how-to-fill-a-column-in-a-data-frame-by-value-enumerating-from-another-vector

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that DF is as in the Note at the end.  Then `to` is the sum of `source_vec` minus the sum of each entry in `from`.

```
transform(DF, to = sum(source_vec) - sapply(from, sum))
```

giving:

```
  from to
1 1, 2  3
2 1, 3  2
3 2, 3  1
```

This also be expressed as:

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>% 
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(to = sum(source_vec) - sum(from)) %>%
  ungroup
```

### Note

```
DF <- data.frame(from = I(list(1:2, c(1, 3), 2:3)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to exclude one element at a time:

```
DF <- data.frame(to=source_vec)
DF$from <- lapply(seq_along(source_vec), function(n) source_vec[-n])
```

output:

```
  to from
1  1 2, 3
2  2 1, 3
3  3 1, 2
```